# Outlook XP to 2007

Tags: windows-7, windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have an old machine running windows XP with Outlook XP on it. I have new computer with windows 7 and outlook 2007 on it.

I want to transfer all my email settings, emails and addresses to the new computer. Information on the Internet regarding this seems to be varied confusing and conflicting.

What is the best/recommended way of achieving a complete transfer?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to install Outlook 2007 on the XP Machine, import the emails from Outlook XP to Outlook 2007, then export the emails as a `.pst` file so they can be imported on the Windows 7 machine.

- First, install Outlook 2007 on the XP machine
- Open it and navigate to **File -> Import and Export**

  [image]
- Select **import internet mail and addresses**

  [image]
- Select Outlook Express

  [image]
- Choose how you want to handle duplicates:

  [image]
- Wait for the import to finish, then you can import account settings as well. From the file menu, go to import and export once again, then select **Import internet mail account settings**

  [image]
- Select Outlook to import from

  [image]
- You now have your emails and settings imported to Outlook 2007 on XP. Go to **File -> Import and Export** once again, and export your settings to a `.pst` file. Import this file on your Windows 7 machine into Outlook 2007.

images from [Vista4Beginners](http://www.vista4beginners.com/migrate-to-Outlook-2007-and-Windows-Vista).

Comment: So I have to waste a outlook 2007 license on a machine I am not going to use not thanks.

Comment: You don't have to register it, use a trial: http://trial.trymicrosoftoffice.com/trialcanada/product.aspx?re_ms=oo&family=officepro&culture=en-CA